# @Inject not working in Singleton but works in API classes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, singleton

I'm setting up authentication in my Jetty API. And I wanted to use dependency injection to inject a class with database functions into the class that checks the provided token against the database.

I've already used dependency injection in my API classes like this:

```java
@Path("/account")
@Api(value = "/account", description = "Web Service for accounts")
public class AccountService {

    @Inject
    private IAccountRepo accountRepo;
}
```

To make this work I created a class which binds the actual class to the interface.

```java
public class RepositoryBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MovieRepo.class).to(IMovieRepo.class);
        bind(AccountRepo.class).to(IAccountRepo.class);
    }
}
```

I registered it like this:

```java
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.packages(
        MovieService.class.getPackage().getName(),
        AccountService.class.getPackage().getName(),
        ApiListingResource.class.getPackage().getName()
);
resourceConfig.register(new RepositoryBinder());
resourceConfig.register(new AuthenticationFilter());
resourceConfig.register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
```

But when I try to use it in my TokenValidator class, the accountRepo is always null.

My TokenValidator looks like this:

```java
@Singleton
public class TokenValidator implements ITokenValidator {

    @Inject
    private IAccountRepo accountRepo;

    private static ITokenValidator instance = null;

    private TokenValidator() {
    }

    public static ITokenValidator getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TokenValidator();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    //Some token validation logic here
}
```

I expected the @Inject to work right away but it doesn't. I've allready tried a bunch of things like registering the TokenValidator the same way the API classes are registered but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the TokenValidator? You need to also bind that (like you did the other two services) and inject it into wherever you want to use it. The `@Singleton` has no effect here.

Comment: I'm mostly using it in a filter witch checks if somebody is logged in before they can access a method in the API class.

Comment: You have to inject it. You can't instantiate it. And to inject it, you have to bind it like you did the other services.

Comment: Your comments helped me fix it. Thanks a lot! Can I give you credit in some way? or should I maybe make an answer myself explaining how I fixed it?

Comment: Go ahead and make an answer.